# Referencing table in another database

Tags: sql-server, database, reference

I want to use two SQL Server databases running on one server. I know that there is a possibility to create a SQL query on both databases but from programming scope it's not so much comfortable because I don't have the secondary database yet and code modifying (and also query modifying) is not the best method how to make yourself happy when secondary database will come in (for example from bug reason).

Is there possibility to make something like reference inside primary database (like reference variable in programming language)? So let's say I will have `DBP` (primary) database and `DBS` (secondary) databases.

I will create a table in `DBS` called `secondaryTable`. And in `DBP` I create table called `secondaryTableReference` and tell `DBP` that this table will be taken from `DBS.secondaryTable` so every time I will work only with primary DB and it will handle the communication between databases. Is that possible to automate this cross database querying or I have to write every time and everywhere long queries?

I don't like this more DB querying but customer wants that in order of storage and sync reasons.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using data replication? That is handled on the server side, and you don't have to take care about it in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the kind of reference you describe is called a table synonym in SQL Server.

```
USE DBS
GO

CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[secondaryTableReference] FOR [DBS].[dbo].[secondaryTable]
GO
```

Then you may query it as though it is a table in your primary database.

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[secondaryTableReference]
```